# python context protocol: why __enter__ and __exit__ method can't be defined in object?

Tags: python, with-statement

My understanding was, that in order for this snippet to work:

```
with some_obj:
    # do something
```

the `some_obj` object must have `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. And this is more or less the only requirement.

The following code demonstrates, that this is not correct:

```
class X:
    pass

def my_enter(*args, **kwargs):
    print("enter ", args, kwargs)

def my_exit(*args, **kwargs):
    print("exit ", args, kwargs)

some_obj = X()

some_obj.__enter__ = my_enter
some_obj.__exit__ = my_exit

with some_obj:
    print("inside with")
```

Even though the `some_obj` obviously have attribute `__enter__` the above code fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tst_with.py", line 17, in <module>
    with some_obj:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Interestingly, if I replace the two lines where I add methods to object with the following:

```
X.__enter__ = my_enter
X.__exit__ = my_exit
```

everything is ok.

Is there any reason why object having these magic methods is not enough for `with` statement to work?

(I encountered this problem when crafting a mock object, and the original code was more sane than the code above.)

Comment: I don't think the duplicate answers your question. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup; it's definitely more helpful :)

Comment: Because *dunder magic methods need to be on the class* due to optimizations always skipping instance look-up. I know there's gotta be a dupe around here somewhere

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, iz_ thank you very much! I did not know about this optimization.